# How to handle ContextMenu item click on DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

```
private void DataGridView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        ContextMenu m = new ContextMenu();
        m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Cut"));
        m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Copy"));
        
        int currentMouseOverRow = DataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex;
        int currentMouseOverCol = DataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).ColumnIndex;
        if (currentMouseOverCol != -1 && currentMouseOverRow != -1)
        {
            DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1.Rows[currentMouseOverRow].Cells[currentMouseOverCol];
            m.Show(DataGridView1, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        }
        if (DataGridView1.GetCellCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected) > 0)
        {
            //current code
                Clipboard.SetDataObject(dgvPCInfo.GetClipboardContent());
                //PASTE menu item code here

            //how can I modify to see which entry was clicked?
            /*
                if (menuitem == "Cut")
                    do something
                else if (menuitem == "Copy")
                    do something
                else
                    don't do anything
            */
        }
    }
}
```

What's happening is

- If I right click on a gridview cell and the menu popups up, I click
  away from it the code inside `if (DataGridView1.GetCellCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected) > 0)`
  still executes but I don't want it to.
- If I click on 'Cut' both cut and copy code fires, hence I am trying
  to use the `if` conditions to ensure I only fire the code needed
  based on the selection.

How can I do the following:

```
    if (menuitem == "Cut")
        do something
    else if (menuitem == "Copy")
        do something
    else
        don't do anything
```

I didn't see any MS Docs to handle the conditions. Can someone please help.

Comment: [Context Menu in C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/context-menu-in-C-Sharp/) - [ContextMenu Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.contextmenu?view=netframework-4.8) - [C# ContextMenuStrip Example](https://thedeveloperblog.com/contextmenustrip)

Comment: I am not using a `ContextMenuStrip`... `ContextMenu`. Thanks

Comment: That's a museum component, read the remarks. Use the strip unless you have a very good reason to stick with it. Besides, the referred links show you how to create both. You don't need to keep creating new components on mouse click event. Create it once by the designer or code, assign it to the `ContextMenu` property of the `DGV`, handle the click event of each menu item to do what its suppose to do. Remember, this component implements the `IDisposable` interface, so, don't create it like that.

Comment: Thanks I will check it out and thank you for the fyi :)

Comment: Sure, most welcome.

Comment: I added a strip and used the same way i created my `FILE` menu and it worked correctly!